# How can we prove that we can draw a line connecting any two dots?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

Recently, I encountered a question which asks you to prove that any two points may be connected by a line. How can we prove this?

Thank you

Comment: I really don’t think it can be proved. Because this is Euclid’s first postulate.

Comment: @insipidintegrator It can actually be "proven" using a combination of the first and second postulate. See my answer.

Comment: The "geometry" tag might suggest you have plane Euclidean geometry in mind, but tags don't serve to replace a clear formulation of the problem in the body of your Question.  Please edit to add those aspects (setup and goal) which are missing.  At the same time add context such as where you "encountered" the problem and what research or effort you made before posting.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [Euclid's Postulates](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclidsPostulates.html) to prove this statement.

From Euclid's first postulate, we know that a straight line segment can be drawn joining any two points.

Then from Euclid's second postulate, we know that any straight line segment can be extended indefinitely in a straight line.

It logically follows that by indefinitely extending the straight line segment joining any two given points given from the first postulate, any line can be drawn joining said points.

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Euclid's **postulate** number $1$ is as follows.

A straight line segment can be drawn joining any two points.